# OpenCV detecting handwritten equal sign operator wrong

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to recognize a handwritten math operator `=` with the OpenCV library, however, I am running into the issue where it can only recognize things that can be drawn in one stroke.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps



img = cv2.imread("sum.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Gaussian Blurring to reduce noise
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

#Adaptive Thresholding to account for different light/shadows
threshed = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)


morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3,3)))

conturs_lst = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]


for cnt in conturs_lst:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

This code leads to this behavior instead, where the equal sign's two parts are bounded in separate boxes.

Input image:
[image]

Actual Output:

[image]

Does anyone know how it would be possible to modify my code to allow for the entire equal sign to be under one bounding box?

Comment: You should try to increase the height (y-axes) of your morph size, e.g 15,17,19,21,..., in your code it is 3, which is very small to the size of the equal sign.

Comment: Is the x-axes value ok in this circumstance?

Comment: Yes, x-axes 3 is enough

Comment: Hm, well it's now recognizing more of the equal sign but is bleeding into other bounding boxes: https://imgur.com/a/3CgOQTw. Do you have any other additional advice?

Comment: You should try something like this: `cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 15));`I don't know how did you try it?

Comment: You can try different values.

Comment: I tried that in a similar manner, however, up to 24, nothing would change. After 24, the behavior shown in the image commented above was then seen.

Comment: Could you give your original image?

Comment: Original Image is shown above

Comment: It is not the original image, the original means that you did not draw anything else on the image, but you have already drawn rectangles on the image.

Comment: My bad, it is located here: https://imgur.com/a/L8AOEs9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
cv::namedWindow("result1", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::namedWindow("result2", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(R"(FRfLi.png)");

// to gray
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(gray, gray, 80, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

cv::morphologyEx(gray, gray, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 27)));
cv::imshow("result1", gray);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(gray, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
    cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    rect.x -= 3;
    rect.y -= 3;
    rect.width += 6;
    rect.height += 6;
    cv::rectangle(img, rect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
}

cv::imshow("result2", img);
cv::waitKey();
```

After morphing you will get this result:

[image]

And detecting contours you will get this result:

[image]

**NOTE:** *The code is in C++, you can just consider the steps which how it is implemented.*

I hope it can help you!